# How can I make a C#/Winforms application that has different form (GUI) elements based on build configuration (Debug/Release)?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a C# application that I am working on that has a lot of functionality used internally that I do not want to appear in the Release build.

I've read the conditional methods document [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288458%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Is it possible to apply those techniques so that winforms elements are not built into the release build? For example, can I have a button for "Open Extra Debug Functionality" on the form that has a [Conditional("DEBUG")] so that the button does not appear in Release build?

Answer (score 5):

You could use preprocessor directives to hide the button:

```
#if DEBUG
    MyButton.IsVisible = true;
#endif
```

Then the button will only be visible if compiled using DEBUG configuration. If not compiled using DEBUG, the code between the directives will not be included in the compiled application.